# How can I count ESTABLISHED connections in Go?

Tags: networking, go, connection, cross-platform, netstat

I'm trying to do basically this in Go:

`netstat -an | grep 2375 -c`

I need to count the number of connections to the Docker daemon in my regression test for a connection leak bug. However, because I run this in multiple places in different OS (local dev box, CI, etc), I cannot rely on the "netstat" tool, so I wonder how can I do this in a more programmatic way in Go?

I looked around the net package and could not find anything that would help. There are some libraries that basically replace netstat:

https://github.com/drael/GOnetstat
https://github.com/dominikh/netstat-nat

But they are not cross-platform compliant (Mac and *nix). Any idea how can I achieve this?

Comment: And including netstat in the docker image / container is not an option?

Comment: The docker daemon can only run on linux, why does this need to be cross-platform? Otherwise, why not just write the 2 or 3 different functions to do it on each platform? (are you missing `netstat`? do you have `ss`?)

Comment: If all else fails, try reading the netstat source code and make the same system calls from go using `syscall`.

Answer (score 0):

In linux this info is exposed in the `/proc` filesystem.
Use [os.Getpid](http://golang.org/pkg/os/#Getpid) and query the info in `/proc/<pid>/fd`. Most likely a simple count is good here, if you need more see the [proc man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html).

Cross platform compatibility for this kind of thing is going to be roll your own, as the ways of identifying open fd's for a process are very per platform. If you simply need to compile, and pass some tests for this on non linux platforms you can use [Go's per platform](http://blog.gopheracademy.com/advent-2013/day-23-multi-platform-applications/) support to make this a no-op on other platforms, or implement an appropriate solution.